# HQL join unexpected token

Tags: hibernate, hql

i have some tables:

`Order(orderID,orderDate, orderItem (OneToMany) )`

`OrderItem( id, order(manyToOne) , book (manyToOne) )`

`Book (id, title, cost)`

`User(id,username,password,email)`

I have `orderID=42` , i need to get it's `Books` info and `userId`

Here is my query to get this tables joining:

```
from Order or inner join or.orderItems ori inner join ori.book where or.orderID=37
```

But this error happens:

```
 unexpected token: or near line 1, column 26 [from com.obs.model.Order or inner join or.orderItems ori inner join ori.book where or.orderID=37]
```

**UPDATE**

`Book` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String author;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String isbn;
    private String description;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double cost;
```

`Order` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer orderID;
@Column(nullable = false)
private Date orderDate;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private User user;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<OrderItem> orderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
```

`OrderItem` entity:

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Order order; // F.K to Order table

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Book book; // F.K to Book table

@Column(nullable = false)
private int quantity;
@Column(nullable = false)
private double totalPrice;
```

`User` entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String username;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String email;
```

OrderItem:

[image]

Orders:

[image]

`Book`

[image]

Comment: `or` is a reserved word. Don't choose `and` or `select`as a replacement.

Comment: @JBNizet Now i have no error, But there is no records in result!

Comment: @JBNizet `orderID=37` exists in `order` table.

Comment: Either you have no item for this order, or none of the items have a book. Your inner joins do nothing expect filtering out orders without items and without books.

Comment: @JBNizet There is a record in `orderItem`  with `orderID=37` in orderItem table and has a book with `bookid=5` .

Comment: Does the book belong to the orderItem with ID 37? Show us the contents of the three tables. Show us the code of your entities.

Comment: @JBNizet Let fetch the `userID ` and `Books` info of `orderID=42`

Comment: @JBNizet Since the userId of `orderID=37` is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OneToMany bidirectional association between Order and OrderItem is incorrect. You in fact have two independent associations. The ManyToOne uses the order_OrderID join column, and the OneToMany uses an additional join table that you haven't shown.

In a bidirectional association, one side is ALWAYS the inverse side of the other. In a OneToMany bidirectional association, the one side MUST be the inverse side:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<OrderItem> orderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
```

Also, note that using CascadeType.ALL on a ManyToOne association makes no sense. You don't want to delete the book of an OrderItem when you delete the OrderItem. That wouldn't work anyway, since other OrderItems reference the same book.

Comment: So i should remove the `ManyToOne` from `orderItem` to `order` , correct?

Comment: No. You should replace the orderItems field declaration in Order by the code in my answer. Adding the mappedBy attribute makes it the inverse side of the ManyToOne association from OrderItem to Order.

Comment: Ok. Now the extra `order_orderItem` table should disappear, correct?

Comment: Yes, it should disappear. I really advise you to not use Hibernate to generate your database schema. Generate it the way you want it, using SQL (or FlywayDB, or Liquibase), and then map it using Hibernate. You shouldn't have tables in your schema that you don't even know what they're for.

Comment: Your query is correct, otherwise executing it would throw an exception. Whether it does what you want it to do is another matter. But you didn't tell what it should do. As I said, the inner joins only have as effect to exclude orders without orderItems, and orders which only have order items without a book.

Comment: What is your mean about `exclude orders`? Every order record in `Order` table has a corresponding `order Item` in `OrderItem` table.

Comment: Each `order` has one or more `orderItem`, and each` orderItem` has exactly `one` book.

Comment: What I mean is that if this query will return the order having the given ID, unless it doesn't have any order item, and unless all its items have no book. If that's what you want the query to do, then it's fine. What do you want the query to do? Why did you add thos joins?

Comment: Suppose i have an `orderID=43` , now i want to get this order's `userId` and `book info` (contains title, cost, isbn,...)

Comment: Actually i am creating a table (user orders table) when user clicks on it's row (each order) and want to delete it, i get that's row `orderID` (with primefaces single selection) , and delete/ update that row (order).

Comment: The you should use `select o.user.id from Order o where o.id = :id` to get the user ID, and `select distinct item.book from Order o join o.orderItems item where o.id = :id` to get the books of the order.

Comment: Well, can i do this two query in one query?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have the userId several times, since the query will return several books: `select distinct o.user.id, item.book from Order o join o.orderItems item where o.id = :id`

Comment: Or you could also load the order, its user, its items and its books in a single query: `select distinct o from Order o left join fetch o.user left join fetch o.orderItems item left join fetch item.book where o.id = :id`.